# Type of multivariable regression for repeated measurements

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

We have data on 6 blood biomarkers (continuous measurements) each of which has been measured at different time points (every 6 hours for 3 days) after heart transplant.

Our aim to is assess which of these biomarkers can predict heart transplant rejection, so the outcome variable is grouped into rejection vs no rejection.

If we had a single timepoint biomarker measurement, then a multivariable logistic regression (in order to also adjust for other variables) would be my choice. But am not sure which method is better suited for this type of data if I want to evaluate them at each of the different timepoints, and overall.
I shall greatly appreciate your advice.

Nelly

Comment: Does your outcome (heart transplant rejection) always occur after your 3 days of measurements? If not, you might run into a problem with [survivorship bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias) when using the later measurements.

Comment: It doesn't always occur after 3 days, but its the measurements we have, so survivorship bias will be a limitation. Any method suggestion?